# Mounting Azure File Share on linux docker container

Tags: c#, azure, docker-compose, azure-file-share

I have a server-side program that is containerized in a Linux container (on Docker).

The program receives a file path via a grpc call and has to read data from that file.

The file location is from an Azure SMB file share, which is mounted on a Windows machine on the client application.

This client application sends the file path to the server application as a string. The path would look something like "T:\TestData\myFile.txt"

Is there a way to mount the file share in the server-side container such that I can use normal System.IO calls on the filepath ("T:\TestData\myFile.txt") in order to read the file?